# Returning Responses Based Upon Adjacent Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba, date, text

I have made some adjustments to my original question.  Firstly, a caveat that I am not a VBA elite by any stretch of the imagination, so this is just what I am trying to parse together for ease of workflow.

Taking into consideration the comments given, I decided to include formulas in hidden cells that would help to make the process a bit easier, but I am still getting errors and am not sure exactly what is causing them. I have a column (rows 3-1500, col.U) that returns the name of the day of the week (it is reading the "dddd" of the date value that is entered into Column C (rows 3-1500))  and then I am trying to get Column M to return "Yes", "No", or "Sunday" depending upon the values stored in Column U... I keep getting the "Application-defined or User-defined Error" message, and am not really sure where the error is coming from.

Note: this sub is within my worksheet module of the specific worksheet, I tried moving it outside as a public module, but it was throwing errors still.

```
Sub IsWeekend()
For i = 3 To 1500
If Cells(i, 3) <> 0 And Cells(i, 20) <> "" Then
If Range("U3:1500") = "Sunday" Then
Range("M3:1500") = "Sunday"
ElseIf Range("U3:1500").Text = "Saturday" Then
Range("M3:1500") = "Yes"
Else
Range("M3:1500") = "No"
End If
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In any scenario, you shouldn't even be using VBA for this - a worksheet formula will suffice:

---

**=IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)<6,"No","Yes")**

---

But the fact that you're getting an Application Error and not a 'Subscript out of range' error would suggest to me that you maybe have this code in the wrong place - perhaps in a worksheet module instead of a code module?

Also, if this code is being called by a change event, then you really should be using manual event handling to stop an infinite loop occuring.

Comment: If I did decide to go the route of implementing a worksheet formula, if there a way to designate three different possibilities?  I.e. if I wanted three different possible answers depending upon whether the date was vbSunday ("SUNDAY"), vbSaturday("Saturday"), or any other vbweekdays ("No")?

Comment: WORKDAY() returns a number representing a day of the week, in my example 1 = monday, 2 = tuesday etc.. so you just test the value of that number

Answer (score 0):

This line is giving you your error

```
Set X = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,3).Value
```

You cannot assign the value of a cell to a variable declared as a range.

Based on your code, it looks like you want X to be text and not a Range object.

Here is what your code should look like (I think):

```
Sub weekcheck()
    Dim X As String

    For i = 3 To 1500
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,3).Value <> 0 Then
            X = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,3).Value
            If X = True Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,3).Value = "Yes"
            ElseIf X = False Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,3).Value = "No"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  On the "Set X = Worksheets("Sheet1") line, I get an error "Object required". Any guesses on what I may be missing?

Comment: I edited the answer, I forgot to remove the `Set` from the begging of that line.